Linux email server configuration: the postfix relay_domains setting and sending email
I am trying to set up an email server on an Arch Linux VPS using postfix and dovecot. I'm using plain unix password authentication, in which dovecot handles SASL authentication for postfix. For the purpose of this discussion, let's say my domain is at mydomain.com.
Regardless of how I vary the settings that I discuss below, receiving mail works fine.
With the default postfix settings for mynetworks and relay_domains, I thought that my postfix-dovecot-SASL set up would just enable authenticated senders (= unix users who are part of the mail group) to send emails. But when I try to send a test email to a gmail account, I get the error
550 5.1.1 <user@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: outside mail is not deliverable
To try to see why I'm not able to send, I started experimenting with the relay_domains setting. Putting
relay_domains = mydomain.com, gmail.com
I can successfully send a test email to my gmail account.
However if I put
relay_domains = *
the test email doesn't make it through, but if I put
relay_domains = *, mydomain.com, gmail.com
then the test email does make it through. I know that in the end I don't want to touch the relay_domains setting, and certainly not to set it to *, but I find it thoroughly weird that the * setting, which is meant to be the most permissive, is being completely ignored.
Can anyone give me a clue what's going on here, or suggest what else I should focus on to figure out my email sending problems?

EDIT: here are some more configuration details.
Some settings in postfix main.cf:
compatibility_level = 3.9

mail_owner = postfix

myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
mydomain = mydomain.com
myorigin = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks_style = host
default_transport = error: outside mail is not deliverable
home_mailbox = Mail/Inbox/

inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# SMTP security settings
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks

smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /path/to/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /path/to/key.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

# added for SPF
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
     permit_sasl_authenticated
     permit_mynetworks
     reject_unauth_destination
     check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf

# added for SRS
sender_canonical_maps = socketmap:unix:srs:forward
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
recipient_canonical_maps = socketmap:unix:srs:reverse
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient, header_recipient

postfix master.cf:
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
         reject_non_fqdn_recipient
         reject_unknown_recipient_domain
         permit_sasl_authenticated
         reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
... etc ...
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
... etc ...
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
policy-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
srsd  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn
    user=postsrsd
    argv=/usr/bin/postsrsd -c /etc/postsrsd/postsrsd.conf

Some dovecot settings:
protocols = imap lmtp
auth_mechanisms = plain login

service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  user = root
}


How do you send mail? In general you want to adjust permitted senders (e.g. whitelist localhost), and use authenticated submission for anything else.

relay_domains is probably NOT a setting you want/need to use for this, especially not with a wild-card as that could make your mail server an open relay that will be quickly abused by spammers. - Normally you either allow only authenticated senders to use your mail server for sending out e-mail (requires additional SASL configuration) or you set up IP-address restrictions like the manual proposes to allow relaying mail from unauthenticated senders from your network

Postfix (sensibly) goes out of its way to make it hard to run an open relay. OTOH there are a lot of configuration directives involved in configuring relaying. Only one line of configuration is mentioned in this question. What version of Postfix? What else is in main.cf? Particularly smtpd_relay_restrictions?

Have updated the question slightly to indicate how I authenticate.

Can you show us your configuration? How is submission set up?

Have updated to provide more configuration details.
